# How do I stop rendering multiple tables after every updation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an angular code which uses a TradingView widget of forex-cross-rates. Now I have provided the user with a checkbox list to add and remove currencies from the table. But whenever I update the list of currencies, I need to call the function that renders the widget. The problem is that it creates a new widget and I can't remove the previous widget. So, there are multiple widgets rendered onto the screen. I want to delete the previous widget and just keep the new widget in it's place. This is the `typscript` file:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forex-cross-rates',
  templateUrl: './forex-cross-rates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forex-cross-rates.component.css']
})
export class ForexCrossRatesComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  symbol: string = "forex-cross-rates";
  settings: any = {};
  widgetId: string = '';
  counter = 0;

  public currencies = [
    "EUR","USD","JPY","GBP","CHF","AUD","CAD","NZD","CNY",
    "TRY","SEK","NOK","DKK","ZAR","HKD","SGD","THB","MXN",
    "IDR","KRW","PLN","ISK","KWD","PHP","MYR","INR","TWD",
    "SAR","RUB","ILS"
  ] ;

  public user_currencies = [
    "EUR","USD","JPY","GBP","CHF","AUD","CAD","NZD","CNY","INR"
  ]

  @ViewChild('containerDiv', {static: true}) containerDiv: ElementRef;

  constructor( private _elRef: ElementRef, private router: Router ) {
  }

  forexCrossRates(user_currencies) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.widgetId = `${ this.symbol }_fundamentals`;

      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener( 'message', ( e: any ) => {
          if( e && e.data ) {
            console.log(e);
            const payload = e.data;

            if (payload.name === 'tv-widget-no-data' && payload.frameElementId === this.widgetId) {
              this.containerDiv.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
              }
            }
          }, false,
        );
      }
      this.settings = {
        "width": 840,
        "height": 400,
        "currencies": this.user_currencies,
        "isTransparent:": true,
        "colorTheme": "dark",
        "locale": "in",
        "largeChartUrl": "http://localhost:4200/forexcrossrates"
      };

      const script = document.createElement( 'script' );
      script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-forex-cross-rates.js';
      script.async = true;
      script.id = this.widgetId;
      script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( this.settings );
      this.containerDiv.nativeElement.appendChild( script );
      const brandingDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
    } );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.forexCrossRates(this.user_currencies)
    console.log(this.containerDiv)
}

//Function that adds and removes elements from currencies list:
  AddCurrency(currency) {
    console.log(currency)
    if(this.user_currencies.includes(currency)) {
      var index = this.user_currencies.indexOf(currency);
      this.user_currencies.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("Removed:"+currency);
      console.log("Updated watchlist:"+this.user_currencies);
    }
    else {
      this.user_currencies.push(currency);
      console.log("Pushed:"+currency);
      console.log("Updated watchlist:"+this.user_currencies);
    }
    this.forexCrossRates(this.user_currencies)
    console.log("AddCurrency")
    console.log(this.containerDiv)
  }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="heading">
<hr>
<h1 style="padding-left: 20px;">Forex Cross Rates</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Currency</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
    <td *ngIf="user_currencies.includes(currency)"><input class="btn" type="checkbox" checked (click)="AddCurrency(currency)">{{currency}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="!user_currencies.includes(currency)"><input class="btn" type="checkbox" (click)="AddCurrency(currency)">{{currency}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="height: 300px;   margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;" #containerDiv>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Comment: You will need to remove the previous script tag and div. To identify which tag you want to remove, you can set a unique ID to the script tag and div, and create a function that removes the tags (find element by ID and remove them from the dom), and run the function before appending new tags to the DOM.

Comment: Do I add `script.UniqueID = something` after `script.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to use either elementref or renderer to remove the script tag from the div before you rerun the function that adds the script tag again. 
Try adding this function to your component:

```js
  removeForexScriptTag() {
    const forexChartScript = this._elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${this.widgetId}`);
    console.log(forexChartScript);
    forexChartScript.remove();
  }
```

then add a call to it right before calling this.forexCrossRates() inside your addCurrency() function. Also, notice the id used in the querySelector() call. You don't need a symbol for this widget, and you only need one at a time, so you don't need it to be dynamic. You could just set this.widgetId to something simple at the top of the component, like 'forex-chart'.
This change should remove the script tag, which will remove the chart, and then add it again with the new currency list.